# decode 16bit number from BLE sensor

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, decode, 16-bit

Im reading minor data from TMPS BLE sensor. In this minor 16bit number value is encode Pressure value (bar), Temperature (°C) and also battery status I think.
I can't figure out how to decode this value but I can simulate this.
For example I can show.

```
read value - 39976 = 3.9 Bar = 0 °C
read value - 41000 = 4.0 Bar = 0 °C
read value - 42024 = 4.1 Bar = 0 °C
read value - 51000 = 5.0 Bar = 16 °C

This is minimum and maximum values for Temperature range in same pressure value
read value - 46848 = 4.6 Bar = -40 °C
read value - 46974 = 4.6 Bar = 86 °C
read value - 46975 = 4.6 Bar = 86 °C + Battery Alarm
```

Can you help me find some logic how can I decode this value in this case please?

Comment: I suspect this TPMS sensor is an NXP FXTH870xD.
Google for the datasheet and look at page 87.

Comment: I found a lot of datasheets for this model what you say but everywhere they say only for 8-bit numbers . Can you give me link for specify datasheet what you mean?

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2618548.pdf